# Runtime exception at 0x00400030: address not aligned on doubleword boundary 0x10010004

Tags: assembly, mips

can you help me

i've been written this simple code just for store int and float values to build my compiler correctly .

it give me this error

line 19: Runtime exception at 0x00400030: address not aligned on doubleword boundary 0x10010004

Go: execution terminated with errors.

```
.text
.globl main
main:

li $a0, 0   #a
sw $a0, -4($fp)
li $a0, 3   #b
sw $a0, -8($fp)
li $a0, 5   #c
sw $a0, -12($fp)
.data
s: .float 2.1
.text
l.d $f0, s
s.d $f0, -16($fp)
.data
a: .float 4.5
.text
l.d $f0, a   ##line 19
s.d $f2, -20($fp)
```

What can I do in this case ??

Comment: `ld.d` is a `double`-precision load (which is why it needs 64-bit alignment), but your data is only single-precision `.float`.  Use `ld.s`.

Comment: it's work ^_^ Thank you